# Whats a good PHP app/project deployment package?

Tags: php, deployment, web-applications

I've been reading about Capistrano, Pake, and Phing and I'm just not finding what I need. It seems like these deployment packages all assume that you have full access to your deployment server, that is SSH access.

What I need is a good deployment package that works with SVN and is able to deploy via FTP or via SSH. Anything out there able to do this?

Comment: Hey, let me know if you have feedback, e.g. if my answer was helpful at all. I'll try to extend otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [weex](http://weex.sourceforge.net/). It's an ftp client to upload web pages.

I think in your case, I'd package my release and transfer that. The most simple approach is creating a tag (from trunk), then run an SVN export (locally) and then upload the remainder. You can wrap that in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn cp http://server/trunk http://server/tag/$1
svn export http://server/tag/$1 ./local
weex yourprofile
```

(Run with: `./tagging.sh`)

... also, create a profile for weex (`yourprofile`), before you run that.

The other tools you mentioned require a lot, but they also work really, really well. I always use capistrano when I deploy straight from SVN. In some cases I also use PEAR to deploy my websites and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Phing and Capistrano should be able to deploy to a server via SSH (capistrano) or FTP (phing).  I do know that both work with svn but they both work a little differently.  From my experience with Capistrano, it connects to the server via ssh and runs the checkout/export.  Phing seems a lot like a scripting language where you tell it what to do and when using an XML format.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use Phing without needing SSH access: Just create a build path where you copy all files to and create the necessary production config files. Then you can use `FtpDeployTask` for copying the files to the server.